# jQuery-ui Autocomplete not finding control on Master page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm struggling with the jQuery-UI Autocomplete on a master page.
I've loaded the jQuery.js and jQuery-ui.js in that order, in the head section of the master page.
What I need to do is very common, I'm sure, but perhaps the idea it's on a master page is getting in the way.
Here is `<body>` code that will fill the autocomplete input (id=autocomplete) with hard-coded values outside an ajax call.
I realize it's useless to call ajax for data and not use it, but I'll deal with that later...baby steps

```
<%-- Trying some autocomplete stuff --%>
<label for="autocomplete" style="color:yellow;">Language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var wsUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("http://localhost/CommonContent/CCWebService.asmx/HelloWorld") %>';
    var fillMe = "[id$='autocomplete']";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: wsUrl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (dave) {
            alert(dave);
            //FillAutocomplete(fillMe);
       },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("1!\n" + errorThrown + "\n" + jqXHR + "\n" + textStatus);
        }
    });
    FillAutocomplete(fillMe);
    function FillAutocomplete(id) {
        autodata = ["c++-001", "java-002", "php-003", "coldfusion-004", "javascript-005", "asp-006", "ruby-007"];
        alert(autodata);
        //$("[id$='autocomplete']").autocomplete({
        $(id).autocomplete({
                source: autodata,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var label = ui.item.label.split('-')[0];
                alert(label);
                var value = ui.item.value.split('-')[1];
                alert(value);
                //store in session
                document.valueSelectedForAutocomplete = value
            }
        });
        alert("Filled");
    }
</script>
```

Again, this WORKS (but the data is hardcoded).  I get the alerts in the following order: success from ajax, then the autodata, then the filled notice.
Additionally, it works if I use the fillMe variable set to "#autocomplete" or if I hard code it in the FillAutocomplete function.
Obviously, since it works, the input is able to have the autocomplete property.

Here's everywhere else where I tried that I simply get 
Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

1. Putting the autocomplete code directly inside the success
2. Call the filling of the autocomplete INSIDE the success of the ajax call (uncomment `//FillAutocomplete`) (comment the other call)
3. Starting with `$(function() {
   $('#autocomplete).autcomplete({...`
4. Using some form of `<#='autocomplete.ClientID()'#>`

I have a sneaking suspicion it's not finding the control, not really that the control doesn't have support it.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE: More Information**
I've added the screenshot below to show the error in its full glory.  And sorry for repeating myself but I'm wondering if it's due to master page somehow, or somehow the jquery-ui is NOT loading before the call to the autocomplete method (since it's "object doesn't support....")

[image]

---

**The Cause and Solution:**

It seems that the Ajax call was trying to complete before the remote file jQuery-UI was loaded.  As **RAM** suggested in the comments below, I downloaded all remote files and they're part of the project now.  Now the scripts load in the correct order and the autocomplete method is available on the input.  Thanks **RAM**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to how to use jquery autocomplete in asp.net
http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/102/JQuery-ajax-autocomplete-extender-textbox-using-json-response-type.aspx

Comment: Nope, still getting Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Comment: It is "finding" the control, because when I change
'("autocomplete").autocomplete' to 
'("bill").autocomplete' I get a compilation error.

Comment: Where you added your jquery-ui reference? add it right after jquery.js reference.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry that's a mess, I don't have the 'comments' here down, but they're added one right after the other.

Comment: Can you check jquery-ui.js loaded or not in your chrome browser developer tools sources?

Comment: It does load it, but I can't tell when.  Could it be somehow AFTER the ajax call?  And can I force it  to load first?  I thought that might be what the `$(document).ready` was for, but I might have that wrong.

Comment: Download the jquery js files locally and place them in your project and refer them in your page locally.

Comment: OK, I know this is getting ridiculous, but I put them in my project (main directory, not /scripts folder) and referenced them in the <head> section and now I really don't think jquery is loading, as I get "$" undefined.  And I tried moving it to the <body> as well.

Comment: And that's probably due to the child page not finding the master page main directory as easily since the master page is a virtual directory.

Comment: Place the css and js in root directory of project and give ref as 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery-u‌​i.css"> 
<script src="/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
<script src="/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: I put it in the root directory called CommonContent.  Then I put the references as

Comment: '        <script src="/CommonContent/scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
        <script src="/CommonContent/scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="/CommonContent/scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />'

Comment: THAT DID IT.  Thanks for sticking with me, RAM!

Comment: So it was running the AJAX (asynch) **before** finishing the page loading even though I had the document.ready() function being used?

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax call was trying to complete before the remote file jQuery-UI was loaded. As ***RAM*** suggested in the comments, I downloaded all remote files and they're part of the project. Now the scripts load in the correct order and the autocomplete method is available on the input.

Thanks ***RAM*** - that did it.